# How to enable the search control on the select2 widget in Yii version 2.0.43 and bootstrap4

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, yii2

I am using yii 2.0.43 with bootstrap4.

If I configure Select2 widget to allow single selection as shown in the code below, the search control on the select input does not work. It is not editable.

```
  <?php
    echo '<label>Roles</label>';
    try {
        echo Select2::widget([
            'id' => 'user-roles',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'name' => 'roles',
            'data' => $listOfRoles,
            'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Roles',
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

However, if I can configure the widget to allow multiple selections as shown below, the search control on the select input works.

```
  <?php
    echo '<label>Roles</label>';
    try {
        echo Select2::widget([
            'id' => 'user-roles',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'name' => 'roles',
            'data' => $listOfRoles,
            'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Roles',
                'multiple' => true
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

I don't want the the select input to allow for multiple selected values. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`['pluginOptions']['tags']`:

> if you wish to display tags selection, use this option. Usually you must set this to true with the options['multiple'] enabled. However you can set this to true to add custom tags for both single and multiple select. When options['multiple'] is enabled, the tags work very similar to a multiple select input and reads and sends data as an array.

https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

you must set `['pluginOptions'][''allowClear'] => true'` for single select - see https://select2.org/selections#clearable-selections

Comment: The Select2 widget has an input field where I can type something to search among the options in the select dropdown. This input field is what I want to function.

Comment: ааа! input name: multiple `roles[]`, single `roles`